# Locking value of a field once created

Tags: 8, feeds

I've been using the Feeds module to create/update some of my content types.

I was wondering if there is a way to "lock" the value of a field once it is created.

I've searched for a module called: Lock Field Values. But it's in development.

https://www.drupal.org/project/lock_field_values

I was wondering if there is a way to add conditionals on import. For example, if a field has a value, then don't updated or just lock the value of the content.

I appreciate any input. Best!

Edit: I'm using Drupal 8

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8. Thanks for the reminder! I can't believe I forgot to add that.